# How to Upgrade Symfony from 1.2.4 to 1.2.7

Tags: symfony1

I have a Symfony 1.2.4 application, taken and modified from the [Symfony sandbox application](http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_2/my-first-project), there was no effort made to make sure that the Symfony engine was separated from my application, so now the Symfony engine is just a folder inside my application.

What is the best way to upgrade from Symfony 1.2.4 to 1.2.7? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

First, one has to move the Symfony framework from sandbox application, then upgrade the Symfony framework using PEAR as [detailed in this post](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/05/move-symfony-framework-out-of-sandbox.html).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

download new sandboxed version of symfony, take data and lib fonders from that archive and out it in your project folder (overwriting existing data and lib folders). after that clean your projects cache and rebuild model (and forms and filters).

```
php symfony clear:cache
php symfony propel:build-all
```

or if using doctrine:

```
php symfony clear:cache
php symfony doctrine:build-all
```

this will always work for minor revisions ( 1.2.3 to 1.2.9 or 1.1.2 to 1.1.5). for upgrades from 1.0 to 1.1 or 1.2 or 1.3 you will have additional steps ( you have detailed instructions for that in documentation)

Comment: Afaik, for version changes in the same major release, you don't have to rebuild your model; the ORM should not have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using SVN and/or installing symfony in the lib/vendor folder of your project. This will make symfony project dependant which is just useful in case of multiple symfony projects on the same server.

Comment: Hmm... If installing the Symfony in the folder of my project, that will cause a problem when I need to upgrade my Symfony version, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 1.2 is a **Stable** version, what does it mean?

> **Stable** : The symfony team is commited to fix bugs and security
>   problems for stable releases until the
>   end of the maintenance. In average, we
>   release a bug fix version a month.
>   **These versions never contain new
>   features, even small ones, but only
>   bug fixes**. So, they are always
>   backward compatible, **easy and safe to
>   upgrade to**.

Like Oncle Tom said, if you're working on multiple Symfony projects, it will be easier to update them if they're sharing the same Symfony library.

Checkout the Symfony lib from the SVN Repository :

```
daemon@dev:/home/dev/symfony$ svn co http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.2
```

Edit your config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php :

```
#require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
require_once '/home/dev/symfony/1.2/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php'; // use the shared lib instead
sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    // for compatibility / remove and enable only the plugins you want
    $this->enableAllPluginsExcept(array('sfPropelPlugin', 'sfCompat10Plugin'));
  }
}
```

Then you're done. You're now using a shared and easy to update Symfony library, and you have updated your project.

To start new projects :

> daemon@dev:/home/dev/sfProjects$ php
>   /home/dev/symfony/1.2/data/bin/symfony
>   generate:project Project

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd add a thought. It was previously considered best practise to have a single location for symfony on a server, as one could upgrade that and magically upgrade all sites on a single server. In practise, it's not that easy. Firstly when moving sites from one server to another, one potentially has to repair symlinks or absolute paths to library folders. Also, as @deresh says, one needs to clear the cache between upgrades - which takes time on multiple projects, and may bring them down until they are all done.

So in summary, these days I embed symfony 1.x in any symfony project, rather than referencing an external location. It brings a "known good version" of symfony into version control, makes it easier to deploy, and upgrading is just a question of deleting `lib/symfony` and `data/symfony` in a development copy, and replacing them with the `lib` and `data` folders from the new tarball. These should be committed and then the project can be deployed on the server easily - `svn up` and `./symfony cc' if you're using Subversion on the server.

In general you don't need to rebuild your models, unless you know that the version of your ORM has changed between symfony releases.